# Why こころ is read as ごころ?

Tags: kanji, rendaku

What's the difference between the Kanji *心(**kokoro**)* and the kanji inserted after another kanji like in *乙女心 (otome**gokoro**)*? Why the kanji in the first example is read as **kokoro** and in the another exemple is read as **gokoro**?